# How to do JSON filtering by boolean field in AWS CloudWatch?

Tags: json, filter, boolean, amazon-cloudwatch

My cloudwatch logs are JSON formatted and filtering by different fields have been no issue until I tried to filter by a boolean field.
I have a boolean field called `low_physical_memory` (the line looks like this `"low_physical_memory": false,`) and I try to filter by it either being `true` or `false` but my filter returns nothing even though I can check the unfiltered log that I should get matches in both cases.
Variants that I've tried with no luck:

- `{$.msg.data.db_memory_usage.low_physical_memory=false}`
- `{$.msg.data.db_memory_usage.low_physical_memory=False}`
- `{$.msg.data.db_memory_usage.low_physical_memory=FALSE}`
- `{$.msg.data.db_memory_usage.low_physical_memory="false"}`
- `{$.msg.data.db_memory_usage.low_physical_memory=0}`
- `"\"low_physical_memory\": false"` this one works but it's not a JSON filter and feels more like an ugly hack.

So to repeat the question from the title, how do I perform JSON filtering by boolean field in AWS CloudWatch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax for checking a boolean is:

`{$.msg.data.db_memory_usage.low_physical_memory IS FALSE}`

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/FilterAndPatternSyntax.html for more information.